# IBM Bluemix - Unable to start a container even after job success

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

What is wrong in this deployment ?

Why a container is not created and running ?

It is a fork project from ice-pipeline-demo project in IBM Bluemix

> ----- START logs ------
>
> LOGMET setup failed with return code 2 IMAGE_NAME:
>   registry.ng.bluemix.net/fs_container_demo/infydevopsdemoimage:3
>   debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog debconf: (Dialog
>   frontend will not work on a dumb terminal, an emacs shell buffer, or
>   without a controlling terminal.) debconf: falling back to frontend:
>   Readline debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline debconf:
>   (This frontend requires a controlling tty.) debconf: falling back to
>   frontend: Teletype dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: 
>   Initialization complete Init runtime of 0m 53s Starting deployment
>   script git clone https://github.com/Osthanes/deployscripts.git
>   deployscripts Cloning into 'deployscripts'... Deploying using clean
>   strategy, for myApplicationName, deploy number 3 Cleaning up previous
>   deployments.  Will keep 1 versions active. No previous deployments
>   found to clean up Container Information:    Group Id Name Status
>   Created Updated Port
>
> Routes:  Getting routes as e-mail id ...
>
> host   domain   apps    No routes found Running Containers:
>
> Container Id Name   Group  Image  Created  StatePrivate IP  Public IP 
>   Ports
>
> (Use '-q' to display container names non-truncated) IP addresses
>   Number of allocated public IP addresses: 0 Images:
>
> Image Id Created  Virt SizeImage Name
>
> 5996bb6e51a11afbca89793940269abf8b7b Oct 16 17:20:51 2015
>   0registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibm-mobilefirst-starter:latest
>   ef21e9d1656c5c90b8cb74eff007d6bb3aa8 Aug 26 21:53:12 2015
>   0registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibm-node-strong-pm:latest
>   2209a9732f35a906491005f87c130bb73e26 Jul 15 16:24:27 2015
>   0registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibmliberty:latest
>   8f962f6afc9a30b646b9347ecb7f458bf75b Jul 15 16:18:04 2015 8549240 
>   registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibmnode:latest
>   90b7d9479645b76b9e359105985c9f47dc6f Dec  7 04:25:31 2015
>   0registry.ng.bluemix.net/fs_container_demo/infydevopsdemoimage:3
>
> To send notifications, set SLACK_WEBHOOK_PATH or HIP_CHAT_TOKEN in the
>   environment Execution complete
>
> Finished: SUCCESS
>   -----END ----

Thanks
Sachin

Comment: try add this "ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive" in docker file

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to open a support request directly from your Bluemix console using the support/help widget: in this way you'll involve IBM Containers support team in checking and fix this issue. They will be able to perform in-depth investigation of your error.

Please provide org and space guids and some details on the image you used (for example the Dockerfile if you have it).

You can retrieve org and space guids using CF CLI (when you already logged in):

```
cf org <orgname> --guid
cf space <spacename> --guid
```